# Prove that $f(z)=|z|$ is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

So, I'm not sure if it's actually correct, but I'm trying to prove that $f(z)=|z|$ is holomorphic (and in fact entire). I get stuck when trying to use the definition explicitly.

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: There is no chance that a non-differentiable function in zero is entire.

Comment: a real-valued, non constant function cannot be holomorphic ;-)

Comment: $f(z)$ is not a function lol

Comment: @Shadock: Yes it is. What makes you think otherwise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you can even show that a holomorphic function which only takes real values has to be constant:
Let $f =u+iv: \mathbb C \to\mathbb R$ be holomorphic. Then Cauchy-Riemann implies that $\frac {\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac {\partial v}{\partial y}=0$ and $\frac {\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac {\partial v}{\partial x}=0$. Hence $f^\prime =0$ and $f$ is constant.
As $|z|$ is not constant, it is not holomorphic.

Answer (score 3):

$|x+yi|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Now use $f(x+yi)=u(x,y)+v(x,y)i$ with appropriate $u,v$, and see that the Cauchy-Riemann equations do not hold.

Answer (score 0):

$f(z)=|z|$ is not a holomorphic function.

The main idea are as follow:
Since $|z|^2=\bar{z}z$, it is suffices to show $\bar{z}z$ is not differentiable. In fact, from direct calculate:
$$
\frac{\overline{(z+\Delta z)}(z+\Delta z)}{\Delta z}=\bar{z}+2z\frac{\overline{\Delta z}}{\Delta z}
$$
Obviously, $\frac{\overline{\Delta z}}{\Delta z}$ do not have limitation as $\Delta z\rightarrow 0$(let $\Delta z$ goes to $0$ along real axis and image axis and they are not agree).

Thus, $|z|^2=\bar{z}z$ is only differentiable in $z=0$ and then  $f(z)=|z|$ is not holomorphic.